# str_replace multiple strings

Tags: php, joomla2.5, str-replace

I want to use str_replace te replace some values in a variable and get a variable named $username with the value USERNAME. It works fine for one value but not for multiple values.

This works..

```
$myabsoluteurl=JURI::current();
$replacestring='http://www.website.com/index.php/component/comprofiler/userprofile/';
$usertemp= str_replace($replacestring, '', $myabsoluteurl);
```

However there are four possibilities how a url can look so i need 4 variables

```
$replacestring1='http://www.website.com/index.php/component/comprofiler/userprofile/';
$replacestring2='http://www.website.com/index.php/instellingen/userprofile/';
$replacestring3='http://www.website.com/index.php/component/comprofiler/';
$replacestring4='http://www.website.com/index.php/instellingen';
```

How can get al four possibilities stripped so i can place the remaining value in a variable? The username is always placed behind one of the four urls...

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `$replacestring`as an array, and then run a `for` loop within the array.

```
$replacestring = array('string1', 'string2');
foreach ( $replacestring as $string ) {
    // do stuff
};
```